# ListView not scrolling for Xamarin.Android app

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've placed a fragment tag on my page for a google map and a listview surrounded by a linear layout tag underneath the map.  Does anyone know why my list view isn't scrolling.  I set my listview fastscrollenabled setting to true and it still doen't scroll.

```
 var locationService = new LocationService(_geoCoder);            
 listView.Adapter = new ListOfLocationAdapter(this, locationService.GetLatLongOfAddresses());
 this.listView.FastScrollEnabled = true;
```

Here is the XAML I use for the layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:rowCount="2"
  android:columnCount="1">
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#FFDAFF7F"/>
     </LinearLayout>
  </GridLayout>
```

Here is the listadapter code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:minHeight="50dp"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="#ffffff">
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CustomerName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip" />
     </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

I tried removing the relativelayout tag, but that didn't do anything for me.

Comment: set your LinearLayout height & also orientation

Comment: Hi Ranjith...I added the orientation and height, but I'm still not getting scrolling.

Comment: check my answer & update me.. incase if not working

Comment: Hi Ranjith...this didn't work either.  I'm going to add my listview adapter code.

Comment: My personal suggestion -> dont use android layouts.. use Xamarin forms & XAML to design listview


https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/

Comment: I made a basic demo from your codes, but didn't reproduced the problem, the ListView is still scrollable. Could you please share a basic reproduceable demo?

Comment: OK.   So I had maybe 5 records in my list view and it only displayed 3 1/2 (with no strolling).  Then I added 5 more records to the listview and it started scrolling and displayed a few more.  Does this give anyone a clue what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Set weight to your listview & set height to 0dp. This will make it auto-fill any remaining space, causing the internal items of the listview to scroll.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/List"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cacheColorHint="#FFDAFF7F" />
```

Comment: This didn't fix it.  I'll update the post and place my changes in there.  Would posting my listview adapter code and xaml in the post?

Answer (score 0):

When I move the linearlayout around both the fragment and listview the scrolling starts working.  For some reason the linear layout was showing off of the bottom of the android layout making it look like it wasn't scrolling until I added more records.

```
 <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:rowCount="2"
     android:columnCount="1">
     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
            <ListView
             android:id="@+id/List"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:cacheColorHint="#FFDAFF7F" />
     </LinearLayout>
   </GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just set *layout_height* of my *ListView* to **match_parent** value. This solved my problem.